# Asp.net add to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to add from a single textbox to different tables in a database.

I have a addclub webform and i would like to add clubname to a number of different tables.

The following is my current code that i have.

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into youthclublist(youthclubname, description, address1, address2, county, postcode, email, phone) values ('" + youthclubname.Text + "', '" + description.Text + "','" + address1.Text + "','" + address2.Text + "', '" + county.Text + "', '" + postcode.Text + "', '" + email.Text + "', '" + phone.Text + "')", connection);
```

Comment: i have assumed your question for multiple insert. yes you can insert your data from textbox to multiple tables on single click of insert, explain your problem more clearly..

Comment: The problem is tht the current code just adds to one table i would like to know how i would change it so it adds to multiple tables

Comment: You need to read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Inkey - Yes, it is clear what you want to achieve. You did not explain where you are having difficulties. What don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible yes but consider my point below:

1. Think about normal form, it should be possible to design the database so that you only need to alter it on one place. If you have to change the name in several places it is likely not following normal form and the database could be redesigned.
2. The way you are doing the update is not advisable, have a look into SQLInjection attacks as the above code is vulnerable to this. Using parameters in the SQLCommand rather than creating a big string is a better way to do this from a security and performance point.

Hope I have not been too negative

Andy

Comment: +1, excellent advice. Also, if you don't want to (or can't) change the database structure, consider doing your multiple inserts with a stored procedure. And wrap them in a transaction. This will help consistency between your tables.

Comment: Thanks guys really appreciated the answers im getting here

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you use a transaction (and you should use parameters to get around some SQL injection attack problems) like so (this means that all the inserts are done in a single block on the database which is safer than doing them one after the other):

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("BEGIN TRANSACTION;"
            + "INSERT INTO youthclublist(youthclubname) VALUES (@youthclubname);"
// Add all your INSERT statements here for the other tables in a similar way to above (I simplified it to show just one column, but you get the idea)
            + "COMMIT;", conn))
{
    // Add your parameters - one for each of your text boxes
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@youthclubname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = youthclubname.Text;

    // execute the transaction
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```